# Incorrect syntax, expecting '(' in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and I'm getting the error "incorrect syntax near '20'. Expecting '('". I'm getting it for every line right before the comma. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE roles 
(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(20),
    salary INT(8),
    department_id INT (10),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Your code works fine in MariaDB 10.5, MySQL 8.0, and SQLite 3.27. Fails for Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, Firebird, and PostgreSQL 12. But none of them gave the error you reported.

Comment: When asking a question related to SQL, it's always important to also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as the syntax and functionality between them varies widely. This is stated pretty clearly in the description of the SQL tag, if you read it.

Answer (score 3):

Data type INT is not set size. You can try this code:

```
CREATE TABLE roles (
    id INT identity(1,1),
    title VARCHAR(20),
    salary INT,
    department_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: How do you know jcase1 is using SQL Server?

Comment: I see jcase1 set tag is SQL and message error "incorrect syntax near '20'. Expecting '('"

Answer (score -1):

try to change to this.

```
CREATE TABLE roles (
id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
title VARCHAR (20),
salary INT,
department_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: [Is "try this" bad practice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196187/172661) *Try this* is a suggestion, and you've provided no reason as to why the OP should *try this* or how it will solve their problem.